# Use of xi:include in Orbeon

Tags: orbeon

I created a form using Orbeon form builder, and i included in its form instance the content of an xml file using :

```
<xi:include href="oxf:/path/file.xml" xxi:omit-xml-base="true" />
```

When i save the form in form builder and edit it, i get a new form, and when i publish it and run it in form runner i get a blank page.

Can you tell me please what's wrong with the xi:include ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you want to include the whole content of an external file as the instance, use:

   ```
   <xforms:instance id="main-model-instance" src="oxf:/path/file.xml"/>
   ```

   Here we have the model instance xml in external file at `/path/file.xml` and we are using this file into our form and have named the model instance as `id="main-model-instance"`
2. If you need to add part of the instance from external file, then insert that piece dynamically during `xforms-model-construct-done` event, e.g.:

   ```
   <xforms:action ev:event="xforms-model-construct-done">
       <!-- Extracts the element some-section from file.xml and uses it as the 
            root element of the fr-form-instance -->
       <xforms:insert context="instance('fr-form-instance')"
            origin="doc('oxf:/path/file.xml')/root-element/some-section" />
   </xforms:action>
   ```

Comment: but the content of file.xml is not the whole main instance, it's only a part of it, the rest is hardcoded.

Comment: ok, if thats the case, then insert that piece into main model instance at model-construct-done event. See my answer, i have add this update.

Comment: @KaipaMSarma Exactly. I just edited your answer to fix a typo in the name of the event (it is `xforms-model-construct-done`). Also, instead of using a separate instance, you can directly use `doc('oxf:/path/to/file.xml')` in the `origin` attribute.

Comment: Ok good, that works fine, I just added something in your example:'<xforms:action ev:event="xforms-model-construct-done" if="xxforms:instance('fr-parameters-instance')/mode = 'new'">
    <xforms:insert context="instance('fr-form-instance')"
         origin="doc('oxf:/path/file.xml')/external-section" />
</xforms:action>' therefore, the instance is inserted only when creating a new form.

Comment: @avernet: Thanks for edit. Its good to know about doc() used in origin attribute.

Comment: @trin86: Good to see this is helpful. Please upvote or accept the answer so that it helps others

Comment: @KaipaMSarma You're welcome; and thank you for the initial response! I also change the example a bit in an attempt to make it clearer that doc() returns the document node, not the root element, unlike instance().